# Outbound link tracking with a redirect

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I have set up Google Analytics to track [outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en). However, I have also installed a WordPress plugin called [Amazon Link Localizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-localizer/) that modifies the outgoing URL such that its final form is `prourls.com?url=www.amazon.com` instead of `www.amazon.com`.

Is it possible to modify the Analytics script such that these outbound link clicks can still be tracked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STEP 1: Add the `trackOutboundLink` script to your website.**

Add this code in the `<head></head>` section of the page's HTML: *(the full script is at the bottom of this page, but use this one to help minimize the page size)*

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink=function(t,e){var n,o="object"==typeof t?t.href:t,a=document.createElement("a");function c(){document.location=o}e=e||o,a.href=e,/\bprourls\.com?$/i.test(a.host)?e=(n=/[\?&]url=([^&#]+)/.test(a.search)&&RegExp.$1||"")?decodeURIComponent(n):e:/\blinksynergy\.com$/i.test(a.host)&&(e=(n=/[\?&]murl=([^&#]+)/.test(a.search)&&RegExp.$1||"")?decodeURIComponent(n):e),"function"==typeof gtag?gtag("event","click",{event_category:"outbound",event_label:e,transport_type:"beacon",event_callback:c}):ga("send","event","outbound","click",e,{transport:"beacon",hitCallback:c})};window.addEventListener("load",function(){var t,e,n=document.getElementsByTagName("a")||[];function o(t){t.preventDefault();var e=this.getAttribute("data-outbound-link");trackOutboundLink(this.href,"1"===e?"":e)}for(t=0;t<n.length;t++)(e=n[t]).href&&!/^#/.test(e.href)&&location.host!==e.host&&""!==e.getAttribute("data-outbound-link")&&e.addEventListener("click",o,!1)},!1);
</script>
```

Note that the script is a modified/customized version of the script provided by Google Analytics:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en — for the old [`analytics.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet) (or `ga.js`) library.
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7478520?hl=en — for the new [`gtag.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/#install_the_global_tracking_snippet) library.

**STEP 2: Add `data-outbound-link="1"` to outbound links' HTML.**

For each outbound links that you want to track, add this to the link's HTML:

```
data-outbound-link="1"
```

(And if you previously added `onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;"` to the link's HTML, then please replace it with the above code.)

So instead of: `<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>`

..use this: `<a href="http://www.example.com" data-outbound-link="1">Check out example.com</a>`

**THE FULL SCRIPT**

Below is the full, unminified version of the *custom* `trackOutboundLink` script: (use this just for reference)

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(link, url2track) {
  var url2visit = ('object' === typeof link) ? link.href : link,
    a = document.createElement('a'),
    b;

  url2track = url2track || url2visit;
  a.href = url2track;

  // Dynamic redirect URLs via Prourls.com; this was for Amazon URLs.
  if (/\bprourls\.com?$/i.test(a.host)) {
    b = (/[\?&]url=([^&#]+)/.test(a.search) && RegExp.$1) || '';
    url2track = b ? decodeURIComponent(b) : url2track;
  // Dynamic redirect URLs via Link Synergy; this was for Footlocker URLs.
  } else if (/\blinksynergy\.com$/i.test(a.host)) {
    b = (/[\?&]murl=([^&#]+)/.test(a.search) && RegExp.$1) || '';
    url2track = b ? decodeURIComponent(b) : url2track;
  }
  // All other URLs are not parsed and expected to be valid outbound URLs.

  function onTracked() {
    //alert('Tracked: ' + url2track);
    document.location = url2visit;
  }

  if ('function' === typeof gtag) {
    gtag('event', 'click', {
      'event_category': 'outbound',
      'event_label': url2track,
      'transport_type': 'beacon',
      'event_callback': onTracked
    });
  } else {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url2track, {
      'transport': 'beacon',
      'hitCallback': onTracked
    });
  }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a') || [],
    i, a;

  function _go(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Track a custom URL address, if specified.
    var b = this.getAttribute('data-outbound-link');

    trackOutboundLink(this.href, '1' === b ? '' : b);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    a = links[i];

    if (!a.href || /^#/.test(a.href) || location.host === a.host) {
      continue;
    }

    if ('' !== a.getAttribute('data-outbound-link')) {
      a.addEventListener('click', _go, false);
    }
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: The previous answer that was added said to remove the onclick handlers. Should those be included or excluded before I add your code?

Comment: Try first with the on-click handlers *included*, or without removing the existing on-click handlers.

Comment: I am using the old analytics.js and so I installed the first block of code. After doing so, the Amazon links are tracked (thanks!) but I cannot even click on the Footlocker links. If I right-click the Footlocker links, I can open the link a new tab but it is not tracked. Please use this page to see what I mean as it has both types of link - https://ballershoesdb.com/players/demar-derozan/.

Comment: Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've updated the answer. Check it out and please let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: It seems that the code does not fire if the link is opened in a new tab. Does that make sense based on how you've coded it and is it possible to modify that?

Comment: We can detect right-clicks (and disable right-click for some if not most browsers) or the action of showing the context/right-click menu, but whether the user chose to open the link in a new tab (or window) or not; that's something I *don't* think we can detect. If, however, you want to track the link *upon* right-clicking on it, then that we can do. I mean, we can track it under, for example "right-click" category instead of "click". Let me know what you think. And sorry if this message wasn't helpful...

Comment: What I can suggest though, is that we detect right-click, and if the link is right-clicked, we change the link's `href` to something like `http://your-site.com/go/?u={URL}`, where `{URL}` is the actual `href` value of the link. Then on the `/go/` page, we track the link and then redirect the user (to the outbound URL; i.e. `{URL}`). If the user cancels the right-click, then we change the link's `href` back to its original/initial value. If you'd like to try this, we can discuss further via chat.

Comment: Thanks Sally for the detailed explanation. It turns out that there is actually a bigger problem in that the non-Amazon links are only tracked about 20% of the time. I have no idea what is going on. This has been such a frustrating problem to solve.

Comment: Either people indeed didn't click on the non-Amazon links.., or they probably use browser extension that disables (certain) scripts on the page or that disables link tracking, or maybe they opened the link in a new tab/window. There are other possibilities, though, such as (although not likely) Google Analytics was the one that didn't (or failed to) record the link/action. You could try using tracking without JavaScript.. you know, plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/thirstyaffiliates/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-link/.

Comment: I tracked the link clicks in real time using GA and can see the Amazon link clicks 100% of the time but only see the other link clicks about 20% of the time. I'm sure that fixing this would require a hands-on approach. I appreciate all the help you've provided!

Comment: I wish I could help you further, but other than the technical/coding side, my GA skills are pretty "so-so", so I wish you all the best and hopefully will get the problem solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**First**, Remove the `onclick` handlers on all of your links.

**Second** Include the following code in your `<head>` block

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    var newUrl = url;
    var re = /prourls\.co.*\?.*url=(.*)/
    var matches = url.match(re);
    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
        newUrl = matches[1]
    }

    // console.log(newUrl);

    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', newUrl, {
      'transport': 'beacon',
      'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
    });
};

var btns = document.querySelectorAll('a.btn');
for (var i = 0, l = btns.length; i < l; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // console.log(e.target.href);
        trackOutboundLink(e.target.href);
    });
}
```

Modified `trackOutboundLink()` now:

- Checks if it is of the form `prourls.com?url=XXXX`
- Extracts the value of the `url` parameter
- Passes that value to the GA event tracking call

Comment: I've added the code but it doesn't appear to be working. If you'd like to check the setup yourself, please look at the "Check Price (Amazon)" link on the following page - https://ballershoesdb.com/shoes/adidas-crazy-explosive-2017/

Comment: The URLs on your site are different to what you outlined in your question. I've modified the regex in my code - please try again and let me know how you go

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the code but I am still not seeing the corresponding event within Analytics when the link is clicked. I know it is working in general as I can see clicks on other links classified as events.

Comment: Please check my additional info above

Comment: It still does not appear to be working. The Footlocker and eBay links are being tracked but nothing related to Amazon (Screenshot - https://www.evernote.com/l/Adw8uB6rMgtKiqHeUXrZVSLhkxNNRDv2LCo). If you want to take a look at the site backend, email the address in the site footer and I can provide the necessary information.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, missed your last message - please see modified response above

Comment: It does not seem like it is working at all now. No outbound clicks are being tracked.

Comment: The code suggested by @Sally CJ is able to track the Amazon links but has broken all other links on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure why my code isn't working when you implement it on your site. It works fine when I test it out via the Chrome Developer Console. I've slightly tweaked my code above. Can you try again?